# Floats - how to restrict floating to subsection only in one section of the document?

Tags: floats, positioning

I have concluded that the package `float` allows figures to float within the section they belong to. However for one particular section I need to restrict the floating to the subsection (without forcing the exact location).

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_Floats I think this is the description of what I need, but I can't work further with it.

> outer counter - the presence of this parameter indicates that the counter associated with this new float should depend on outer counter, for example 'chapter'.

I need to set that outer counter to be subsection rather than section which is the default. however I only need that for one specific section. Everywhere else floats can float...

Seeing this:

```
\newfloat{type}{placement}{ext}[outer counter]
```

I have tried and replaced `figure` for `figuresubsec` on the cases I needed  and used this:

```
\newfloat{figuresubsec}{htbp}{floats-ext}[subsection]
```

however the pictures do appear but don't move to their subsection and they don't appear in the list of figures.

Comment: similar issues are disused here:
[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `\FloatBarrier` command of the [placeins](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/) package.

EDIT: Counters associated with a float may influence float numbering, e.g. "Table 1.3" (third table in section 1 of an article) instead of "Table 3" (third table in an article). Those counters bear no direct relationship to float placement. (In the LaTeX standard book class, there's one indirect relationship: The `\chapter` command acts as a float barrier.)

EDIT2: The `\newfloat` command is used to create new types of floats, e.g. "maps" besides tables and figures. These "maps" may be listed in a "list of maps", but (unless you do some hacking) won't appear in the list of figures.

Comment: `placeins` has a `sections` option that places a `\FloatBarrier` before each section command, so that `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` does what the qner wants.

Comment: @Charles Stewart: The OP seems to want a `\FloatBarrier` for subsections (and only within one particular section), and I don't think there's a package option for that.

Comment: @lockstep: And, indeed, for one particular subsection - I had misread the qn.

Comment: \FloatBarrier can be placed anywhere in the code, so it worked just fine.
I'll keep in mind the automation \usepackage[section]{placeins} for the future

Comment: @lockstep: in book class, '\subsection' is the float barrier (or at least it seems to be)

Comment: @Splashy: I assume you simply placed an explicit `\FloatBarrier` immediately before each `\subsection` in the relevant section?

Comment: @SamB: I think Splashy did exactly that.