# Placing all floats before continuing

Tags: sectioning, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
>   [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections)

What I want to do is really simple: I want to make sure that at a certain point, latex simply inserts all floats that have been created, before continuing to the next section.

Right now I get:

```
Sec 1
Float 1.1

Section 2
Float 1.2
Float 2.1
```

Is there a way to tell latex to dump all remaining floats before continuing with whatever comes next? So that Float 1.2 is inserted before Section 2 starts?

Comment: Does the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4854/floats-how-to-restrict-floating-to-subsection-only-in-one-section-of-the-docum help?

Comment: More than one possible duplicate.

Comment: @Noio Since this question has already answers here, we closed this question to prevent duplicate answers. Have a look at the question links at the top. If that doesn't help, just edit your question, we could reopen it if meaningful.

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` is exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I didn't find it here. Somehow I was searching for the wrong terms I think.