# Section, subsection and content

Tags: sectioning

I have content in the following format:

> Section ->  subsection -> subsubsection1 (lot of images here) -> subsubsection2 (some other content)

Now the problem is that while creating subsubsection2 I want to get it after all images of subsubsection1 (obvious thing) but I am getting the following sequence.

> subsubsection1 -> subsubsection2 -> (images from subsubsection1)

Totally unpredictable.

P.S. I am using report as `\documentclass` .

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Well, your images float away and `LaTeX` puts it to a place where thinks they would fit best. Try to use `\usepackage{placeins}` and type `\FloatBarrier` right before `\subsubsection{Number 2}`.

Comment: does this answer help?  [Floats - how to restrict floating to subsection only in one section of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4856/579)