# What variant float lists exist?

Tags: macros, floats, placeins

I saw question [wrapfig and wraptable not obeying \FloatBarrier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317447/wrapfig-and-wraptable-not-obeying-floatbarrier) and resolved to put `\wrapfill\WFclear` into placeins.sty. But I also wonder if there are more alternative float types or alternative placements that should be supported. I don't mean alternatives to `figure` and `table`, but other collections beyond LaTeX's standard toplist, botlist, deferlist, and dbldeferlist; or other things similar to wrapfig.

I admit I have not dug into the new alternative float placement algorithm for LaTeX, but would welcome hints regarding it.

Comment: `\dbldeferlist` is not used any more, is it?

Comment: In my experience, \@toplist and \@botlist contain floats which WILL appear on the current page. [h] floats which fit are moved directly into the text and will not appear in any list. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats/295526?r=SearchResults&s=1|14.4564#295526 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page/426250?r=SearchResults&s=3|12.7731#426250

Comment: Did I miss any news? What is the "new alternative float placement algorithm" you mentioned?

Comment: I know links are frowned upon, but this is in the LaTeX project, titled "Formatting documents with ﬂoats A new algorithm for LATEX2", https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2000-FMi-TUG-xo-pfloat.pdf; but I thought there was a newer iteration around. At least the package `fewerfloatpages` on CTAN is new.